# Current location with angularjs and yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, yeoman-generator-angular

I have define the config of my module:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

      .when('/models', {
        templateUrl: 'views/models.html',
        controller: 'ModelsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'models'
      })
      .when('/contacts', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'contacts'
      })
      .when('/constructor', {
        templateUrl: 'views/constructor.html',
        controller: 'ConstructorCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'constructor'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/constructor'
      });
  });
```

Is it possible to get information about current user state without using angular-ui-router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the $location service and make use of its path() function.
Here is a link to the docs for location [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

```js
   angular.module('app')
  .run(['$rootScope','$location', 
function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, current) {
      console.log('Current route name: ' + $location.path());
    }
  }]);
```